# (OpenGL) Viewport wont change position on the y-axis

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I'm creating a simple window manager for future projects and I seem to have run into a problem. I have a snippet of code which is supposed to change the viewport's position to the middle of the window whenever somebody resizes it, and it seems to work completely fine when changing position on the x-axis, [as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz6fy.png) Unfortunately, it doesn't work on the y-axis, [instead showing up at the bottom of the window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4McrJ.png) here is the code that handles this:

```
/* create viewport */
if (win->width > win->height)
    glViewport((win->width / 2 - win->viewport.width / 2), 0, win->viewport.width, win->viewport.height);
else
    /* FIXME: viewport appears at bottom of window, i have no idea why */
    glViewport(0, (win->height / 2 - win->viewport.height / 2), win->viewport.width, win->viewport.height);
```

I have changed a number of variables in the equation but none of them yielded any results. I have ran the equation outside of `glViewport` and it  returns the desired numbers. OpenGL is intentionally changing the viewports position to (0,0) and I have yet to figure out why. if it helps at all, I'm using OpenGL 3.3 and SDL2 on a Windows machine.

If anybody could tell me what I need to do to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it. Please and thank you.

Comment: It works for me. Have you tried debug the program to see if the value `win->height / 2 - win->viewport.height / 2` make sense?

Comment: i have ran the equation outside of the function and found that they produce the desired results. is it possible it could be related to my system and not OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run in a similar problem with SDL2 too.

I think the missing part is that you are not considering the aspect ractio value.

Also using SDL2 with Opengl you should consider that the drawable area can be different from the window area.

Assuming w and h the original sizes,
draw_w and _draw_h the current drawable area size,
view_w view_h the viewport area size,
we can calculate it as :

```
SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize(window,&draw_w,&draw_h);

float ratio = (float)w/(float)h;

if(draw_w/ratio < draw_h)
{
    view_w = draw_w;
    view_h = (int)((float)view_w/ratio);
}
else
{
    view_h = draw_h;
    view_w = (int)((float)view_h*ratio);
}

x = (draw_w-view_w)/2;
y = (draw_h-view_h)/2;

glViewport(x, y, view_w, view_h);
```

I have used a similar function applied to a SDL2 filter event as :

```
if(event->type==SDL_WINDOWEVENT && (event->window.event==SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED || event->window.event==SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED))
```